# distance between two signed numbers

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, distance

The distance between two numbers is often calculated like that:

```
long distance(long x, long y)
{
     return x > y ? x - y : y - x;
}
```

However with signed `x` and `y` these subtractions there may overflow and so that function can invoke undefined behavior both in C and C++.

One way out of that issue is to use unsigned type to represent resulting distance. Distance can not be negative so signed type is not needed. Distance between minimum and maximum of signed type should fit into unsigned type of same size. (**Edit:** As chux answered it was not entirely correct assumption.) So I did modify the first function like that:

```
unsigned long distance(long x, long y)
{
    return (x > y) ? (unsigned long)x - (unsigned long)y
                   : (unsigned long)y - (unsigned long)x;
}
```

Does it now correctly calculate the distance between two signed longs in standard conforming and portable manner? If it does not, what would be the fix?

Comment: Pick one, C or C++. The answer may be the same in both, but you should ask separately for each, because they are different languages with different specifications. You can enter the same question separately for each language.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but chances of overflow are there if you are adding two integers and not subtracting two integers ???

Comment: Signed to unsigned conversion uses two's complement, and is well defined, so the above should be well defined. Sadly, given the utterly over-engineered state of the C++ world today, locating all the authoritative cites from the standard that are relevant here would probably take the better part of a day, and I need to go and buy groceries; so I'll say this is well defined, and move on.

Comment: If you redefine the return value of the function in question you can also redefine it's arguments like so:
*unsigned long distance(unsigned long x, unsigned long y)*

Comment: Consider what happens in the second case with calling `distance(LONG_MAX, LONG_MIN)`.    Since `x > y`, the result is equal to `(unsigned long)LONG_MAX - (unsigned long)LONG_MIN`.   Converting `LONG_MIN` to `unsigned long` gives a result mathematically equal to `ULONG_MAX + 1 + LONG_MIN`, so the function returns a result mathematically equal to `(LONG_MAX - ULONG_MAX - 1 - LONG_MIN)%(ULONG_MAX +1)` or `(LONG_MAX - LONG_MIN)%(ULONG_MAX +1)` which is probably not what you expect.

Comment: @MukeshVerma Consider `int x = INT_MIN; int y = INT_MAX; x = y - x;`.

Comment: @peter: why is that unexpected? LONG_MAX - LONG_MIN is precisely ULONG_MAX.

Comment: If the value cannot be negative, why are you taking in ordinary `long` instead of `unsigned long`?

Comment: @InstantChoco The input values can be negative like -7 and -42, however the output can not be negative because distance between -7 and -42 is 35.

Comment: This will only work if both values are negative, in which case you should build a check for it.

If you input -1 and 1, the difference is close to INT_MAX.

Comment: @InstantChoco Can you explain your complaint? It seems to calculate distance(-1,1) correctly: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47f269eb9725a57a

Comment: @ÖöTiib I'm surprised, since the outcome in other contexts is quit different.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be1e5dfc77105aee

Comment: @InstantChoco that is oversimplification what the function does you have switched a and b there.

Comment: @rici C does _not_ specify that `LONG_MAX - LONG_MIN` is precisely `ULONG_MAX`, even though this is exceeding common.  1) With rare non 2's complement  `LONG_MAX +1u - LONG_MIN == ULONG_MAX` is more common.  Further, a compliant platform could use `LONG_MAX == ULONG_MAX`.  I've only come across 1 such case  BITD.

Comment: @chux point 1 is true but it doesn't affect the correctness of the calculation. Point 2 is more serious, since it means that unsigned long doesn't have the capacity to hold the difference. But in that case, there's no hope for a correct computation since long isn't wide enough eithe. At least it's not UB.

Comment: @rici I agree #1 doesn't affect the correctness of the calculation, it just qualifies the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578843/distance-between-two-signed-numbers?noredirect=1#comment92093106_52578843).  #2 Yes, to solve the rare case, code needs wider math - if available.

Comment: @chux: ok, you got me. I edited the comment because it was too wordy, and that made it only applicable in the vast majority of cases. Luckily it wasn't an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does it now correctly calculate the distance between two signed longs in standard conforming and portable manner?

Yes.

Rare exception<sup>1</sup> would oblige using a wider type.

---

Consider the 3 cases when `x > y`

**x >= 0, y >= 0**

Following is trivially correct as the cast does not change *value*.

```
(unsigned long)x - (unsigned long)y
```

**x < 0, y < 0**

Both x,y values are increased by `ULONG_MAX + 1` due to the `(unsigned long)` and the subtraction cancels that out.

```
// is akin to 
((unsigned long)(x + ULONG_MAX + 1) - (unsigned long)(y + ULONG_MAX + 1))
// or
x - y // with unsigned math.
```

**x >= 0, y < 0**

`(unsigned long)y` has the value of `y + ULONG_MAX + 1`, which is more than `x`.  (Assuming `ULONG_MAX/2 >= LONG_MAX`<sup>1</sup>) The difference is negative.  Yet *unsigned* math wraps around, and adds back `ULONG_MAX + 1`.

```
// is akin to 
((unsigned long)x - (unsigned long)(y + ULONG_MAX + 1)) + (ULONG_MAX + 1).
// or
x - y // with unsigned math.
```

**x < 0, y >= 0**

This case not possible as `x > y`.

---

<sup>1</sup>: C does not specify `ULONG_MAX/2 == LONG_MAX` even though that is exceedingly common.  I've only come across this once long ago where it did not apply. It that case it was `ULONG_MAX == LONG_MAX`. `ULONG_MAX/2 == LONG_MAX` is so expected that I doubt a modern platform would risk not doing so.  C does specify `ULONG_MAX >= LONG_MAX`.

> The range of nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the
>   corresponding unsigned integer type, and the representation of the same value in each type is the same. ... C11dr §6.2.5 9

Code could use the below to detect these rare platforms.

```
#if ULONG_MAX/2 < LONG_MAX
  #error `unsigned long` too narrow.  Need new approach.
#endif
```

Comment: So only on platform where LONG_MAX - LONG_MIN > ULONG_MAX it does not work? If that is very exotic then may be it is enough just to static assert that it is not the case.

Comment: @Öö Tiib Yes, some use of `_Static_assert` (since C11) or macro magic.  I wanted to avoid `LONG_MAX - LONG_MIN` as _theoretically_, that could overflow even `uintmax_t` math.

Answer (score 0):

Since unsigned overflow (and underflow) is well defined for C and C++, when 2's complement arithmetic is used your modified function is perfectly fine.

Comment: This seems intuitively correct, but can you expand and prove this assertion?

Comment: To prove it i will need to prove 2's complement arithmetic correctness, which is already proved. Try to find a counterexample, you will not find one.

Comment: @chqrlie if take bytes, `2 - (-2) = 4`, `0x02 - 0xFE = 4` (with overflow), `(-1) - (-2) = 0xFF - 0xFE = 1`. Logic for `long/unsigned long` is the same, but you have more bytes to write.

Comment: @EirNym: I am just asking for a formal proof. Numerical examples can be used to disprove if they are counterexamples, but not to prove a conjecture, unless you show its correctness with an exhaustive enumeration, which is the case of `unsigned long long` values is not practical. user2162550 says it is obvious thanks to two's complement arithmetics... If it is obvious, it should be easy to prove :)

Comment: user2162550 , The proof is not a 2's complement thing.  Code works even with 1s' complement/sign magnitude.

Answer (score -1):

assuming sizeof(unsigned long long) > sizeof(unsigned long) it safe to declare it as : `unsigned long long distance(long x, long y)`

but because nowadays ones complement or another exotic format number are not in a common use (actually it is very unlikely anyone to  have an opportunity to code C on such a machines) the `unsigned long` type can accommodate all possible distances.

Comment: Unfortunately that assumption does not hold on relatively common platforms http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f169edbad5839278

Comment: @ÖöTiib on that systems it is not necessary as I do not know even a single which is not 2 complement. Then the larger size is not needed. On the other hand I have not heard about the one complement system where sizeof(unsigned long long) == sizeof(unsigned long). So your comment means that you did not understand my answer

Comment: I did not downvote it so apparently other people did also not understand your answer. Please edit it.

Comment: The concern for correctness is not a 2's complement vs non-2's complement encoding issue.  It is if the `unsigned long` range is at least 2x the `long` range, which is _very_  common, though not required for a compliant implementation.  With alternatives as suggested here, to avoid padding and sign issues, the assumption needed here is not a size one, but a range one: `#if Alternative_result_type_MAX/2 >= LONG_MAX`.